# Dynamic pivot in SQL : conversion failed

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, sql-server-2017

I have a table that date/time filed is `nvarchar` type when I create pivot table I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT pr[آماده سازی],[فنی],[غیر فنی],[متفرقه],[CIP],[نامنطبق],[نت],[نظافت],[مواد اولیه] from 
>                (
>                   select stoptime,(prdname+convert(nvarchar,prsize))pr,stoptypetext
>     from Table_stop
>     where formnum in (select prdID from Table_production where prddate=iif(1398/06/04 is null,prddate,1398/06/04) 
>     and prdgroup=iif(شب is null,prdgroup,شب) and idline=iif(' to data type int.

My code is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @date NVARCHAR(10) = '1398/06/04',
        @pgroup NVARCHAR(150) = N'شب',
        @idline INT = 4

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(stopTYPE) 
                      FROM Table_stoptype
                      GROUP BY stopTYPE, stopid
                      ORDER BY stopid
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT pr' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select stoptime,(prdname+convert(nvarchar,prsize))pr,stoptypetext
```

from Table_stop
  where formnum in (select prdID from Table_production where prddate=iif('+@date+' is null,prddate,'+@date+') 
  and prdgroup=iif('+@pgroup+' is null,prdgroup,'+@pgroup+') and idline=iif('+@idline+' is null,idline,'+@idline+'))

```
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum(stoptime)
```

for stoptypetext in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

```
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Check you dynamic sql by select @query and copy the sql and see what is issue in your query.

Comment: `SET @query = N'SELECT pr' + @cols + N' from`   what is the `pr` for here just before `@cols`

Comment: JamieD77 pr is production name and size combine together that in blow line in select